# SonarQube Update Center shows nothing

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube 5.2 is up and running. Last week I installed a plugin from update center. Today, when I go to Update Center nothing is shown as available. Updates Only, Available, System Upgrade all tabs are showing `0 available`. I've tried restarting web server.

Has anyone run into this?

Environment: SonarQube 5.2 on Win7 with Embedded DB (still evaluating) running using `StartSonar.bat`.

**Update**
Installed plug-ins are:

C#

Git

Java

JavaScript

ReSharper

SVN

Comment: Anything special displayed in the sonar.log file? Maybe you've got some Internet connectivity issues, that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Logs is showing below `ltsVersion should be defined
ltsVersion seems wrong as it is not listed in SonarQube versions
ltsVersion should be defined
ltsVersion seems wrong as it is not listed in SonarQube versions` Could that be the reason?

Comment: What plugins have you already installed? You can see the list in "Administration > System > System Info" page. Can you please update your question with this list?